# react-native-iap android issue

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I am using react-native-iap for in-app purchase and it is working ios well but not in android.
Please check my code and give me help.

```
requestSubscription = async index => {
   const sku = itemSubs[index];
   RNIap.requestSubscription(sku);
};
```

I am getting The sku was not found. Please fetch products first by calling getItems. But I already getItems using `RNIap.getSubscriptions`. Please help me on this problem.
Thank you very much!

Comment: have you registered the sku on play store?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there might be an issue in registering the sku on playstore. I've cracked both ios and android iap functionality in once by just following this doc. [rn-iap](https://medium.com/@abhayg772/implementing-in-app-purchase-in-react-native-application-3798ca2de5bb) . I would recommend you to check it out and it will surely help.

Feel free for doubts